# Hover текста на font-weight и font-size?

Tags: html, css

При наведении текст подпрыгивает тк меняется font-weight и font-size. Как можно сделать это плавно без подпрыгиваний? Спасибо

```css
a{
display: flex;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
  color: #000000;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

a:hover{
 font-weight: 700;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 17px;
text-decoration: underline;
color: #d6720c;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">ТЕКСТ</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно ошибка в том что вы тег не правильно закрыли? Анимация происходит, да и в соответствии с [документацией](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties), данные параметры подлежат анимированию

```css
a {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000000;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

a:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #d6720c;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">ТЕКСТ</a>
```